# How can I disable the mask for messagebox in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

My ExtJS is 4.1.1 version, and I'm using the messageBox to show a warning dialog, and each components will have their own custom messagebox. Now my situation is that when a messageBox show up, it has a mask behind it and disabled all the other components. However, I want to only show a mask on the particular component which triggers the warning.

```
                    // create messageBox
                    var messageBox = Ext.create( 'Ext.window.MessageBox' );

                    // define configurations for messageBox
                    var config = {
                            title: Locale.gettext( 'Warning' ),
                            icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
                            msg: Obj.errorMsg,
                            fn: function( btn ) {
                                    if( btn === 'yes' ) {
                                            // do something
                                    } else if( btn === 'no' ) {
                                            // do something
                                    }
                                    messageBox.destroy();
                                    _slf.box.unmask();
                            }
                    };

                    messageBox.render( this.box.element );
                    messageBox.show( config );
                    messageBox.alignTo( this.box.element, 't-c' );
                    _slf.box.mask();
```

This piece of code will be used for each box which triggers a warning. So how can I disable the default mask when the messageBox is showed?

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation, I found that I can set the `modal: false` to avoid it show the default mask.